# updating bigquery from command line using standard SQL raises Too Many Positional Args

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to do very simple DML to update a table in BigQuery using standard SQL but it seems that I can't correlate any other tables in the update besides the one I am updating.

```
update dataset.interaction set field = true 
where anotherField in (select field from dataset.anotherTable)
```

Or

```
update dataset.interaction i 
inner join dataset.anotherTable o on o.joinField = i.joinField
set field = true;
```

Both queries raises

```
Too many positional args, still have ['field','=','true'...]
```

Comment: So what is the actual `bq` command that you are using?

Comment: Got it. I was using update directly inside bq shell. I though that as you can write selects direct into bq shell, I could do the same to DMLs. Thanks

Comment: Please provide a proper answer instead of editing the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

As you can use `SELECT` directly into the bq shell (without `query`), I thought that I would be able to do the same when using `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. But the fact is that to run `DMLs`, you'll need to use `query` and it is much easier from the shell using the command `bq query`.

As far as I could understand, you can't use `update` with `inner join` option, only the `in` clause.